# An HTML challenge

Tags: html

[image]

A container that contains a box centered horizontally and a line centered vertically beside the left or the right side of the box. The width of the container may change dynamically so the line should also change its width (automatically). I hope the image explains that well.

Comment: so ... less a question and more a "do this for me"?

Comment: I've tried to do it myself but failed. I do not want to bother anyone if it's difficult.

Comment: @Orcut well it might help if you show the code youve tried, so people can leverage that before attempting to write an (untested) answer.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but I believe it woudn't help as it does not work as intended. So, that's why I have created a picture to show what I've been trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is there going to be other content in this section with the line or will it be all by itself?

Comment: Yes, there might be another box.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 100px; width: 500px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% Red;">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="width: 50%;">
<div style="border:solid 1px black;"></div>
</td>
<td>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% blue;">test</div>
</td>
<td style="width: 50%;">

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: This might be a solution. And actually, I've considered it but hoped for a cleaner way.

Comment: And I think I'll go for it if I do not find anything better.

Comment: Have you tested it in Google Chrome? It does not seem to work in GC.

Comment: Neither does it in Safari for Windows.

Comment: works on chrome as well. what problem did u come across

Answer (score 0):

If the height is static and the only thing that changes is the width, just make the line a background repeating image of a line.

Comment: Yes, the height may be static but the problem with your suggestion would be a line spreading thru the whole box. I need the line to be whether at the right or at the left.

Comment: And also, I need a line to be an html element not an image.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. I assumed the box is a fixed width, so I had to make the line 50% and hide it behind the box.

css:

```
.container
{
   height:100px;
   width:30%;
   position:absolute;
   left:100px;
   top:100px;
   border:solid black 1px;
}

.box
{
   position:relative;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   margin:0px auto;
   background-color:#eee;
}

.line
{
   width:50%;
   background-color:green;
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:50%;
   height:10px;
   margin-top:-5px; /*half the height*/
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```